# Excluding specific columns from sum in R

Tags: r, sum

I have been able to sum columns through various positive methods of retrieving column names. But, need to use a negative method `!` for my code.

I have a vector of characters as,

```
exc2 <- c("Product", "Kazakhstan", "Kyrgyzstan", "Tajikistan", "Turkmenistan", 
    "Uzbekistan", "CASIA", "CHINA2", "China", "China..Hong.Kong.SAR", 
    "China..Macao.SAR", "China..Taiwan.Province.of")
```

The code I am using as follows:

```
kazx5 <- lapply(kazx4, function(x) {x$RESTWORLD <- c(rowSums(x[ ,!c(exc2)], na.rm = T)); x})
```

It gives an error on `!c(exc2)` as `Error in !c(exc2) : invalid argument type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setdiff` to remove columns

```
kazx5 <- lapply(kazx4, function(x) 
         {x$RESTWORLD <- rowSums(x[ ,setdiff(names(x), exc2)], na.rm = T); x})
```

as `!` will not work on character values.

---

To use `!` we can do

```
kazx5 <- lapply(kazx4, function(x) 
         {x$RESTWORLD <- rowSums(x[ ,!names(x) %in% exc2], na.rm = T); x})
```

Comment: DO we have to use `[ ,` while creating a new column. I thought it is more often used while creating a new row.

Comment: Depends which side of `,` you are. Left side of `,` is for rows and right side for is for columns. So `df[1, ] <- NA` would create one row with `NA` whereas `df[, 1] <- NA` would create a column with `NA`.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse` methods

```
library(tidyverse)
map(kazx4, ~ .x %>%
                 mutate(RESTWORLD = select(., -one_of(exc2)) %>%
          reduce(`+`)))
```

Reproducible example with `mtcars`

```
excN <- c("mpg", "disp")
map(list(mtcars, mtcars), ~ .x %>%
       mutate(RESTWORLD = select(., -one_of(excN)) %>% 
            reduce(`+`)))
```